# Is it possible to skip the iteration after the current one?

Tags: python, loops

The `continue` statement ends the current iteration and skips to the next one, but I was wondering if it is possible to skip the iteration *after* the current one.

Example:

In a `for` loop that runs for 4 times (loop count: 1 2 3 4), can you create a statement that becomes true in the 2nd loop, but instead of skipping the rest of the current one it ends the loop first and ends the one after instead?

1 -> 2 (the condition required) (executes the test of the 2nd loop first) -> 3 (3rd loop gets skipped) -> 4

Comment: but i want the loops after the skipped one to be executed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a variable (maybe called `skip_next`) to `True` in one iteration of the loop. Then at the beginning of each iteration, if the variable is `True`, you set it to `False` again and use `continue`.

```
skip_next = False
for i in range(1, 5):
    if skip_next:
        skip_next = False
        continue
    if i == 2:
        skip_next = True
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can create an iterator from the iterable and iterate over the iterator instead, so that you can call `next` on the iterator to skip the next item in the sequence as needed:

```
iterator = iter(range(1, 5))
for i in iterator:
    if i == 2:
        next(iterator, None)
    print(i)
```

This outputs:

```
1
2
4
```

Comment: Maybe `next(iterator, None)` to prevent an exception if the condition triggers on the last element.

Comment: @tobias_k Indeed. Thanks.

Comment: Tried to do this in the console and had a wrong behavior where it prints: "1,
3,
2,
4" instead of "1, 2, 4", worked just as expected when executing from a script though, do you also have the same behavior ?

Comment: @AchilleG Did you `print(next(it))`? (Or maybe the console just echoed it)

Comment: No I wrote the exact same code, once in my console and once in a file that I executed (and worked as expected)

Comment: @AchilleG That's because in Python's REPL environment, any standalone expression that returns a value gets printed automatically. This behavior is meant to be a convenience for debugging but can be confusing in this case. Change the line to a non-expression statement such as `assert next(iterator, None) or True`.

Comment: @AchilleG You can also disable the automatic printing in REPL with the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15535441/6890912).